# Saml profile of XACML in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, saml, xacml

I have to work with Saml and Saml profile of Xacml in dotNet, but I didnt find any implementation of Saml profile of Xacml.

For Saml I will use Saml2 of Codeplex https://saml2.codeplex.com/ and in .Net I will work with Web Api to build restful webservices that have to communicate with an android application.

If someone know something about that I will thank him.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no one has ever implemented the SAML profile of XACML. Besides, it is a very large profile with different options. So you would have to be more specific.

For .Net, there is a XACML implementation of the core specification along with other profiles e.g. Multiple Decision Profile. More info [here](http://www.axiomatics.com/news/233-axiomatics-releases-new-net-policy-decision-point-engine.html).

Comment: Then, if I want to work with the Saml profile, what do I have to do?  Besides, is there any free solution to work with Xacml?  Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I am not sure there is any free .Net alternative. Re. SAML, I have never seen anyone use this profile. What' your use case?

Comment: Something like this. http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/implementing-saml-to-xacml.html

Comment: Thanks for that. You don't need it. I work in the XACML space. I know several products and although many have implemented the SAML profile of XACML to transport the XACML request / response, none use it. Using TLS is plenty enough. SAML is overkill and is also a performance concern. I would steer away from it. BTW the article you pointed to has a couple fallacies in there including the fact that w/out SAML, a XACML request / response cannot be trusted.

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it using SAML and XACML. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't do it using SAML. In my experience, it doesn't add any value (and I've been doing this for 8 years).

Comment: Use TLS + SOAP/XACML or REST/XACML with XML or JSON encoding